# What is the justification for using the Marcus rate equation to model charge transport in organic semiconductors?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, aqueous-solution, physical-organic-chemistry

I am trying to understand the history of how Marcus theory moved from describing electron exchange reactions in aqueous ionic solutions to also being applied to describe transport in organic semiconductors. As in who and when was the connection made and justified?

Comment: I believe the connections between Marcus Theory and electron transfer in organic semi conductors was made in the 80's in the context of understanding electron transfer in the photosynthetic reaction centers. The only reference I can think of off the top of my head right now is:
https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00002a076
If you can, I'd suggest mining through the references in there.

Comment: No sure about the history but basically the Marcus theory can be derived from the spin-boson model see 'Chemical Dynamics in Condensed Phases, Nitzan'. The spin-boson model itself is very closely related to another model called the Holstein model the only difference is the summation of the vibrational states which is in wavevector space for the Holstein model while in the spin-boson model its in real space. 

The Holstein model is well known in solid states physics and I used model polaron transport.